# Why are so many English expressions derived from baseball terminology?

Tags: idioms, american-english

- Get to first base
- Step up to the plate
- In the right ballpark
- etc

Why are so many expressions in common use today based on this one specific American sport? Many of them seem to be used often in corporate environments too -- why is this?

Comment: Because it fits? BTW Get to the first base is normally sexually oriented

Comment: I suspect this question will be quickly closed. It's highly subjective. Beyond saying, "Because lots of Americans understand and love baseball", what more could one say? I suppose a more-answerable question would be if this makes the US different from other countries. Like, do British people use a lot of football (soccer) metaphors, etc?

Comment: @Jay, I'm not sure that last comment is quite cricket.

Comment: Could make a hat trick... At least get the ball rolling

Comment: Woohoo! Go Sox!

Comment: you guys are not even in the right ballpark!

Comment: It's only American English that's affected, by and large. Because only Americans both play baseball and speak English.

Comment: I hear many of these expressions in Britain on a daily basis.

Comment: "so many" is relative, isn't it? You've only listed three examples in your question; how about: _hit the target, miss the mark_, and _long shot_, all from archery or shooting? Or: _get through the weeds,_ and _nip it in the bud_, both related to gardening or agriculture? Wouldn't any commonly-understood domain be ripe for picking metaphors?

Comment: Baseball is an English sport: Evolving from older bat-and-ball games, an early form of baseball was being played in England by the mid-18th century. This game was brought by immigrants to North America . . . (Wikipedia). I'm not saying the expressions mentioned were common before the US imported it.

Comment: This is hopelessly subjective. Glancing at [this Wikipedia page on "sports idioms"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_sports_idioms), I can't help noticing that 4 of the 7 entries under **G** are in fact derived from *boxing* (and none at all from *baseball*). So perhaps it makes more sense to ask why there are so ***few*** baseball-derived expressions, not so *many*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: just off the top of my head, that page is missing "strike out", "left field", and "home run". I think it makes more sense to ask: why is that Wikipedia page missing most of the baseball idioms.

Comment: @Peter: I can't deny that all of those are common enough in the UK, even though very few of us play (or even *watch*) baseball. Perhaps whoever wrote that Wikipedia page was a big fan of boxing. I effectively picked **G** at random before (just because it was the first letter with more than half-a-dozen entries). But I now notice that 4 out of 10 **H**'s are also from boxing *(have someone in your corner, heavy hitter, heavyweight, hit below the belt)*. So even if *home run* had been included, boxing would still *punch above its weight* as a source of idiomatic expressions.

Comment: I don't think the heart of this question is extremely subjective. I think the particular phrasing of "so many" is problematic but I think there is absolutely a way to answer this historically. It is essentially the same type of question as, "Why does English have words with [other language] roots?"

Comment: @JohnLawler: "only Americans both play baseball and speak English" Many of the UK posters on here are likely to assert that only half of that statement is accurate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Baseball was once concerned the Great American Pastime and was a cornerstone of American culture. From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baseball#Popularity_and_cultural_impact):

> Writing in 1919, philosopher Morris Raphael Cohen described baseball as America's national religion. In the words of sports columnist Jayson Stark, baseball has long been "a unique paragon of American culture."

In recent years, American participation in team sports has [drifted toward](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sports_in_the_United_States#Popular_team_sports) basketball and soccer and [attendance at professional](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average_attendances_of_professional_sports_teams_in_the_United_States_and_Canada) football teams typically beat out attendance at professional baseball teams. But the cultural impact of baseball can still be seen in idioms such as the ones you noted.

Comment: I've a long-held belief that baseball's popularity rose and faded with that of radio, because it's such a good radio sport. You don't need to see the action to see what's going on – you always know which team is on offense and which is on defense, and one can follow a game just fine without seeing managers spit in the dugout, pitchers shaking off signs, and batters adjusting their gloves and crotch. Once TV eclipsed radio, basketball and football rose, and baseball began an inevitable decline. Those more visual sports move too quickly for radio, but look sensational on a color TV screen.